# Turn off optimistic locking programmatically

Tags: java, hibernate

I have some code that add fixtures to the database, for test usage. There are some problems, though, with locked entities that have children, as they are kinda saved twice (once when I save the child, and then again when I save the parent). That gives a optimistic lock error, because the version field is always null.

Is there a way to programmatically turn off optimistic locking? Obviously I need to turn it on again afterwards to run the tests properly.

I'm using the following method to save:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "pu")
private EntityManager em;

@Override
public <T extends Entity> T save(T e) {
    return em.merge(e);
}
```

**Background**

The idea is the following, I have a data set for tests that can have a structure like so: a class A that has a required double-sided relationship with a child B. So I have objs a1 and a2 both referencing the same child b1. I hold references for this obj in enums so I can use them in the tests without fetching (e.g. I can query the screen and check if the retrieved name == a1.name). But I also need to insert them to the database. So I iterate all fixtures, saving them. They all have their id set, to guarantee uniqueness (that both a1 and a2 will have the same child, for example). When I save a1, it saves b1 via cascade. It needs to, because the relationship is required, and I would get a constraint violation otherwise. When I save a2, however, it tries to update b1, **which is fine, because they are identical**, but I get locked because my optVersion is null. It happens yhat I also save b1, because I don't know who is child of who, and that makes it all wrong anyway. I don't want to update optVersion dur to performance. I woudn't want to save again either, but that seems impossible to me - unless I could programatically set all cascades to be create but do not update or something (that seems even harder, though).

Comment: "they are kinda saved twice" hmm, probably nothing to do with the locking but with your code logic.

Comment: So when you save a child (standalone) it gets persisted and increase version to 1. After that, you have a parent with a cascade to it's child (which have already persisted)? so parent hasn't up-to-date child. Do i understand it correctly? If so, update your parent to get up-to-date it's children. If i missed,  Please give more details. "switch off/on" optimistic lock is not a robust solution.

Comment: I don't think it's not robust,because it is only in a test env. Updated the question with details to what I am doing.